# PhantomJS web driver mode override page.onResourceRecieved function

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I am using the [Ghost driver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) with PhantomJS.

I need to get the **http response code** of the page thats loading the phantomjs. As its not straight forward to get that in the existing phantomjs implementation, I decided to override the `page.onResourceRecieved` function and get that response code.

But now I got struck that, it can be done easily if I am starting phantomjs with javascript in cli but not able to do it while starting in webdriver mode.

Is there a way to do that?

I tried following the things but both didn't work:

1. I tried starting in webdriver mode with a javascript in cli with the following command:

   > setup/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx/phantomjs ../setup/config.js --webdriver=18824

   But in this approach it fails to start in webdriver mode.
2. I tried to run the javascript to override the page.onResourceRecieved function but that is also not working. The below code doesn't throw any error or change anything:

   ```
   PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
   String script = "page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {  console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', stage ' + response.stage + '): ' +response.url);};";
   Object result = driver.executePhantomJS(script);
   System.out.println(result);
   ```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Comment: Have you found solution yet?